# QMessageManager queryMessages does not work in Nokia N8

Tags: qt-mobility, nokia-n8

I am trying to read SMS messages from Symbian phone inbox. I created an app with Qt Creator and got it working in Symbian Simulator, but in Nokia N8 it cannot read any messages (SMS or email).

Here is my minimal code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QMessageManager>

QTM_USE_NAMESPACE

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QMessageManager mm;
    QMessageIdList msgs = mm.queryMessages();
    ui->textBrowser->append(QString("Messages %1").arg(msgs.size()));
    for (int i = 0; i < msgs.count(); ++i) {
        QMessage message = mm.message(msgs.at(i));
        ui->textBrowser->append(message.from().addressee());
        ui->textBrowser->append(message.to().at(0).addressee());
        ui->textBrowser->append(message.textContent());
    }
}
// ...rest is boilerplate code
```

In simulator this prints the test messages it has. In N8 it displays only "Messages 0" although there are SMS and email messages.

In .pro file I have declared

```
CONFIG += mobility
MOBILITY += messaging
```

I am new to Qt so this may well be something everyone takes for granted. I tried debug and release builds, and also copying the sis file Qt Creator created to the phone and installing it, but the result is the same.

Comment: I asked this also in Nokia developer forums, http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?237679-QMessageManager-queryMessages-returns-0-messages-in-N8 and found a resolution there. I guess I'll answer myself with this info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [User guide: Symbian Signed](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/User_guide%3a_Symbian_Signed). For reading SMS messages, you need to add ReadUserData capability for symbian. In .pro file, add

```
symbian:TARGET.CAPABILITY += ReadUserData
```